# Delayed system sounds

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

My SYSTEM audio is delayed, when I get a notification there is no sound, but there is a background buzzing that tells me the sound has become active.
When testing sound I click Front Right all I hear is "right".

My issue is much like [the one detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218444/sound-output-starts-delayed), except I'm using my GPU's HDMI output.

If I have `pavucontrol` open, the buzzing sound is constant and there is no delay. I hear all system sounds and notifications instantly.

In the above posted thread,user Dr.Evil posts a solution of disabling the audio module idle timer, which I think will cure my issue, but I can't figure out how/where the config document is to make the changes.

I'd also like to get rid of the low buzzing sound if possible,but that's not a real concern because it isn't too overbearing.

My system is:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
AMD Athlon64 dual-core 4200+
Asus A8ZMN motherboard
2GB ram
Nivida GT520 /w proprietary drivers installed

I have `pavucontrol`,`alsa-utils`,and `sox` installed.

Comment: As mentioned in the question you linked, change it in: `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` or `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> and type:

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Change the line to say this instead:

```
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

This is called "commenting out" the line when you place a # at the beginning of the line the configuration listed on that line will not be used.

Next, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Finally, run the following command to restart pulseaudio:

```
sudo service pulseaudio restart
```

Comment: After posting this

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I successfully commented out the module,but after restarting it made no difference,Still getting delayed audio,Movies and Music seem to work fine,but it seems like  simply opening Rhythmbox or Totem initiates the buzzing sound.I should also have mentioned that my system's integrated sound card has never been displayed in audio settings,which is fine since I'm using the Graphics card HDMI,but I wondered if that was a clue to the issue?