# Audio becomes enabled ~5 sec later than the media file starts playing

Tags: sound, firefox, chromium, 19.10

Whenever I watch a video on YT or listen to music elsewhere, the audio only starts playing around 5 sec after the playback started (it's still in sync, just the first ~5 secs are muted).

Here is [a very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874320/audio-starts-playing-3-5-seconds-after-video-does), but I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and in my case the problem only happens in Firefox. Chromium works fine.

Could anyone please suggest an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I've got another OS (win10) on another ssd in the same system. Interestingly, same bug happens from time to time when I use Firefox with that other OS as well. So maybe it's Firefox rather than something Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: But the same bug happens in Ubuntu with VLC. So could this be a hardware issue?

Comment: This solution https://askubuntu.com/a/440787/1010286 worked for me.